# Armature not influencing itself anymore?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm doing some viewmodel animation, my rig is no longer moving like it used to? e.g. previously when i would pose the thumb tip the rest of the thumb would move with it accordingly and follow it around, now the thumb tip moving does not bring any part of the thumb with it and moves statically. this same issue applies to all bones. I think I've changed a setting somewhere on accident? or hit a button randomly? this is really frustrating and I've got no clue how to fix it

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't show us what you have made and you didn't show us any setting you did.